# Favicon in xampp

Tags: php, yii2, xampp, favicon

I am trying to put favicon.ico in `C:\xampp\htdocs` in development environment works ok but in the production server does not work, in Firefox nothing appears, in Chrome appears the default xampp icon.
In the console appears error 302 (Found), I tried it but it did not work.

```
<head>
<link rel="icon" href="/favicon.ico" type="image/ico">
</head>
```

Im using Yii2 Framework, maybe it's a permissions error on the production server maybe with htaccess?

Comment: Have you checked the access/error logs?

Comment: @JayBlanchard in console appears error 302 (Found).

Answer (score 0):

You need to purge browser cache since the old favicon is saved.

The options are:

- Close and open the webpage tab
- Force the reload with Ctrl + F5 or Ctrl + R
- Clean the cache and cookies in the browser settings, over the time lapse you need

Then the recommendation is to set the favicon as png file and setting correctly the 'rel' and 'type' attribute in the link tag
https://www.w3.org/2005/10/howto-favicon